# Problem with Running PDFTexify

Tags: pdftex

I am using WinEdit 10.3. During the running process, I am unable to produce PDF. During the running process I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
{{32}{6 
! File ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.105 \begin{document}

?
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm sure we can help, but first we need to see the document that you are trying to typeset. Make a copy of the document, remove stuff that is irrelevant, and post the rest here. As it seems, the error occurs before `\begin{document}`, so you can probably remove most of the stuff following it.

Comment: Though this is a generic error message, it is unique to your document in its appearance, meanin gwe cannot say much right now, just that a closing `{` brace is missing somewhere. My guess would be to check the titlepage. Maybe you have a percent sign misplaced.

Comment: Try deleting the temporary files (`.aux`, `.toc`, ...) and recompile. If that does not help we will unfortunately need to know a few more details about your document. Ideally you would manage to reproduce the error message with as little code as possible and post a complete example document here (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). (Coming up with such an MWE will probably take some time, but it is definitely worth it.)

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not show the relevant portion of the log, the error is in the `.aux` file, so if you delete the `.aux` it will definitely go for the next run of latex.

It is possible that the error appears again on the second run in which case look at the aux file to see which `\label` is causing the problem. It is a `\label` related to something with number 32 on page 6 (or 60 or 61 or ..., impossible to tell from the fragment quoted.

If you do get an error make sure you always quit (eg with `x`) don't simply abort the job with control-c or killing the terminal window, that can often kill tex while it still has unfinished file writing, leaving the aux file corrupted and generating the type of error that you show where the file ends with a half-written `\@newl@bel` command.